SQL Server Management Studio says 80 MB database needs 160 GB to restore
I have a relatively small DB with perhaps 12k rows in it across 25 tables with about 10 columns on average, mostly ints and varchar. I did a backup and the .bak file was 114 MB, which ZIPped down to ~6 MB.
I then sent it to another user who has SQL Server on their machine so they could play with the data. When they attempt to restore it, they get this message:

There is insufficient free space on disk volume 'C:' to create the
database. The database requires 148,007,092,224 additional free bytes,
while only 15,559,897,088 bytes are available.

I thought it might have to do with trying to restore to the root of C, but they are not, that's just an inaccurate error message. I still had them make a new directory and restore there to be safe, but they get the same message.
I dropped the database on my end entirely and re-built it from scratch using BulkInsert so the transaction log would be minimized, and shrank everything before making a new backup and sending them that. Same issue on their end.
Clarification: after rebuilding the DB as in the para above, the DB file is 72 MB and the log is 8.
I'm at a loss here, has anyone seen this before?

That the backup is 114MB doesn't mean that's how big the database was; backups are compressed. I assume that the source database files are significantly larger, and had a lot of internal "free space". When you RESTORE a database, the files are created at the same size they were when they were backed up. If you had a database file that was 150GB, but contained 140GB of free space, the RESTORED database was mirror that, and you would need 150GB of available storage space on the destination device.

the .bak file was 114 MB, which ZIPped down to ~6 MB. that, very, very unusual and suggests the database has a lot of empty space. Backups will maintain those empty pages. Backups are meant to recover an exact replica of the database and that means recovering the data pages and transaction logs exactly as they were.

"they get the same message." have you tried to restore this backup? It's quite possible whoever is trying to restore is doing something wrong. You can use RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = N'.c:...\backup.bak'; to see the estimated restore size.

Assuming other user does not need TLog. Copy our database on you Server, set Recovery Mode to simple, shrink database, do a "copy only" backup of this new db and send that.

that's just an inaccurate error message no it's not. If you try to restore to drive C, the error will say there's not enough space in C: , not the full path to the individual files. A database can have multiple data files

If you do a restore filelistonly..., you'll see each of the files in the database along with its size in bytes. Alternatively, if you have access to the source database, take a look at its files in sys.master_files.

@ThomA - the source database files are 80 MB.

What does RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = N'.c:...\backup.bak'; show? Did you try restoring on your own machine?

Then someone is doing something wrong, @MauryMarkowitz . We, however, lack the information to know what that is. Perhaps, as silly as it sounds, you ran the BACKUP against the wrong database, or they are trying to RESTORE the wrong one.

@PanagiotisKanavos - db is 14 mb, log is 336.

Can you get the 3rd party to run that statement, @MauryMarkowitz ? is the 3rd party restoring this over an existing database, or will it create a new database?

336 what? Bytes? MBs? If it's 336 MBs it means the transaction log was never backed up before the database was, so all its records were included. Take a transaction log backup before backing up the database

In the FULL recovery model all transaction log records are retained until they're backed up. This allows the database to recover from unexpected shutdowns by replaying the log entries. Check the Recovery Models docs. You could use the SIMPLE model to avoid big transaction logs but should something happen to the data files you'd only be able restore up to the last data backup

I may have came across this, though it would have been some years ago. In your original DB check settings for File growth and Initial file size for both data and log files. Make sure they are set to reasonable values.

I tried various solutions here, but none of them seemed to help. So I switched recovery to simple, shrank, and switched it back. Presto. Seems the log file was "stuck" somehow and the backups weren't causing it to become shrinkable.
